# How to display only certain bins according to bin height with a pyplot histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am currently trying to plot the frequencies from a csv column into a histogram.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.hist(df["attack_website"], bins=100, rwidth=0.7,
fig.savefig("phishHistogram.pdf")
plt.show()
```

Here is the current code I have. There are 2 problems I am struggling with.

1. I only want to display bins where the frequency is greater than 5.
2. On the x axis there is every unique element name. I only want to display the names of the bars that are being plotted.

The column df["attack_website"] looks like:

[Microsoft, -1, allegro, allegro, -1, -1, -1, -1, internal revenue service, -1,.......]

I am trying to plot these frequencies as a histogram but only ones with occurences greater than 5

[Plot of Data using provided code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf9tn.jpg)

Comment: I have to go now. Did you try `plt.ylim(bottom=4.5)`?

Comment: `plt.hist` doesn't work well for categorical data. Seaborn's `countplot` might be an option. Or a bar plot with the result of counting.